# What's the meaning of "pushing at the boundaries of"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Following is a passage from [this](http://www.salon.com/2014/05/31/i_never_meant_to_deceive_him_love_and_betrayal_in_the_virtual_world/) article:

> Heterosexual men flirted with me, and I never bothered to correct them. In my mind, it wasn’t a lie unless my words actively misled. I was **pushing at the boundaries of gender**. Or so I told myself.

What does the phrase *pushing at the boundaries* mean? I have looked it up the phrase, but couldn't find a source that defines it clearly.

Comment: It's pretty transparent imagery. Compare *stretch the limits* and [*push the envelope*](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/push-the-envelope.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boundaries are borders, or limits; to push at them would suggest an effort to expand the space they contain. In this context it is being used to explain that the currently accepted definition of gender would need to be expanded to properly describe the narrators situation.